# DataView RowFilter and valid UK DateTime

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetimepicker

I am attempting to add a row filter to a DataGidView

The column type is a date fetched from a database

i have used a DateTimePicker to allow the user to select a date, however i keep getting the error message

"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

my code is triggered on then ValueChanged event as follows

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = cmbColumns.Text.ToString & " =#" & dtpFilter.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "#"
```

i have tried a number of variations of this, 
a) like passing the datetime to a string variable
b) stripping off the time aspect and constructing the date manually in a string

i ultimately want to confirm that the date is in UK format and that it is valid

Any help would be appreciated as ive been at this most of the day

Comment: A DateTime var does not have a format, try it without all the string conversions

Comment: Just tried just the dtp.value which failed on the same error. I was using the string to format the date to UK standard or else it gets the month and day in the wrong order, despite having a custom format set on the object

Comment: If the column you are comparing to is also a DateTime, comparing a DateTime to a DateTime should work - it will be using the data, not the formatted view you created.  What is the DB and the exact DataType?

Comment: The db is a 2008 mssql instance and it's a datetime datatype within the database.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.CultureInfo = <your uk ci>` anyone?

Comment: a) what you see in the DGV is the result of the culture setting plus any cell formatting.  It is not the actual data. b) MySql has several DT styles, unless it is `DateTime(0)` your filter may fail due to time elements.

Comment: Ok so what I am seeing is just the date within the dgv, however the data table type is datetime. I just want to filter on a date basis and ignore the time aspect. I am on a mssql db and not mysql

Comment: Sorry, misread that - MSSQL has multiple DT types too - is the time being saved to the database?

Comment: The data in the database looks like 2016-02-25 00:00:00.000

Comment: I've just changed the #datetime# to 'datetime'. It doesn't error any more, however it also doesn't display any filtered data

Comment: You are constructing a date literal. Similar to VB rules on date literals,   DataColumn expressions are parsed using the invariant culture(i.e. the date must be in the form of `mm/dd/yyyyy`).  see:  [DataColumn.Expression Property- Remars Section->Parsing Literal Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DateTime` type **does not have a format**.  As the name suggests, the `DataGridView`, presents a VIEW of the data which respects the culture setting of the system as well as any cell formatting you have going on.  Some data under "en-US" culture:

[image]

Without doing anything else but changing the culture, the VIEW changes to:

[image]

They are the same dates just displayed differently. It is all part of the **View** aspect of the DGV.  To filter the `DataView` to a date:

```
zDV.RowFilter = String.Format("ZDate = '{0}'", #10/14/2010#)
```

Result:

[image]

The data in the `DataView` is still data - not formatted for culture or anything else.  Since DateTime's do not have a format, you dont have to worry about it.  The code above passed a **culture invariant/US Date** (m/d/y) in the filter, but it worked.  The reason is because a `DateTime` is just a number and **does not have a format**.

One of the things your code is apparently choking on is the filter expression.  This must be in *culture invariant* order (`MM/dd/yyyy`) the same way you would define a date literal:  `Dim myDT = #02/29/2016#`.

The string format version I used just makes it easy to read and define multiple conditions:

```
zDV.RowFilter = String.Format("ZDate = '{0}' And Color = '{1}' ", dt.Date, "green")
```

Comment: Thabks for your help on this. I have got it working. I can't thank you enough